# Сортировка вставкой с обобщенным типом c#

Tags: c#, .net, алгоритм, инспекция-кода, generics

Написал реализацию сортировки вставками с обобщенным типом, но к сожалению имею мало опыта работы с обобщениями, подскажите где тут могут быть подводные камни?

```
public class Sort<T> where T : IComparable<T>
{
    public static void InsertionSort(T[] array)
    {
        int j;
        for (int i = 1; i < array.Length; i++)
        {
            j = i;

            while ((j > 0)&& (array[j].CompareTo(array[j - 1])< 0))
            {
                T temp = array[j];
                array[j] = array[j - 1];
                array[j - 1] = temp;
                j = j - 1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Было бы интересно услышать ваше мнение по потенциальным багам и отказоустойчивости.

Comment: Не универсально. Вот будет у меня массив школьников и я захочу их для журнала сортировать по фамилии, а для физкультуры – по росту. Как быть с вашим методом? :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP, хороший вопрос!) И как быть?) надо создавать отдельный интерфейс?

Comment: А какого рода обратную связь вы хотите? По производительности, по элегантности кода, по отказоустойчивости, по потенциальным багам и т.д.?

Comment: @АндрейNOP, как вариант могу предложить оборачивать ваших школьников в декоратор в одном случае в журнальный в другом в физкультурный и в зависимости от декоратора реализовывать `IComparable`

Comment: @VadimOvchinnikov, думаю по багам было бы самое интересное? ну и про отказоустойчивость конечно тоже. По производительнсоти понятно в худшем случае он не очень. Но в данный момент меня интересует именно работа с дженериками и их особенности

Comment: Почитайте про способы сравнения в .Net, посмотрите как это в Linq, например, сделано

Comment: @VasyaMilovidov В целом, как мне кажется, всё хорошо. Так порефакторить разве что можно: 1) объединить объявление и инициализацию `int j` и `j = 1`; 2) убрать лишние скобки в условиях внутри `while`; 3) заменить `j = j - 1` на `j--` или `--j`.

Comment: Не хотите добавить метку [tag:инспекция-кода]? Также ваш вопрос можете задать на https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ — получите больше обратной связи.

Comment: Я бы подумал на тему более адекватных называний класса и функции. Например поменять их местами... Класс думаю можно тоже статическим сделать.

Comment: По поводу универсальной соритировки красивее всего думаю будет выглядить метод принимающий лямду `Func<T,T,bool>` функции сравнения, тогда и по возрасту легко будет сортировать и по росту... Если лямбда пустая, то использовать стандартную.

Comment: Или не накладывать на T ограничение `IComparable<T>`, но передавать `Func<T, TKey> keySelector` и, при необходимости, `IComparer<TKey>`